# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in php

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm running Windows Server, MS Sql and IIS6.  I am trying to connect php to ms sql database, and I keep getting the following error from the script

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in .... on line x

I have install zend studio in `C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendStudio-5.5.0` directory.  Configure IIS server and set the path variable to `;C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendStudio-5.5.0\bin\php5` also.
The zend studio folder contains php4 and php5 inside the bin dir. I have added `extension=php_mssql.dll` in the `php.ini` file which is inside the `C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendStudio-5.5.0\bin\php5` folder. And added `php_mssql.dll` in the ext dir. `php.ini` file is placed in windows path `C:\WINDOWS` also.

Comment: Have you restarted the server since changing the ini file?

Comment: yes, i have and restart system also

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103751/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-query

Comment: or you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402713/how-to-get-mssql-work-with-php-5-3

Answer (score 0):

To get changes made to php.ini to take effect, you must stop and start the IIS web service.

Also, mssql requires: `ntwdblib.dll` to be available on the Windows PATH. It is better to add the php folder to the Windows PATH instead of moving any files around. Re-logon or reboot your computer to get any changes made to the Windows PATH statement to take effect.

Comment: I have added php5 folder as it is from C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendStudio-5.5.0\bin\php5 to the Windows path. And ntwdblib.dll is also in the windows path. My php.ini file contains only extension_dir, extension, inlclude_path

Comment: "And added php_mssql.dll in the ext dir."  is it also added to php.ini? like uncommented?

Answer (score 0):

mssql_* API are no longer available on recent version of PHP 
[This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php)

you may need fix and compile yourself as it does not included in the open-source package.