# Connecting to SQL Server 2008 through PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, wamp

I need to connect to a SQL Server 2008 through PHP (WAMP, latest version). I have the sqlsrv drivers installed and set up and they do show up in `phpinfo()`.

I'm using the following lines to connect to my DB, using Windows Authentication:

```
$serverName = "(local)";
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"MyTestDatabase");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions) or die("Error!");
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => IMSSP 
        [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP 
        [1] => -49
        [code] => -49 
        [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2011 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2011 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 
        [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2011 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2011 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
    ) 
    [1] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => IM002 
        [SQLSTATE] => IM002 
        [1] => 0 
        [code] => 0 
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified 
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    )
)
```

Any help would be great, but please be specific since I really don't know my way around WAMP except for a few basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by a permission issue in the registry. There is a key where the path to the native client is stored and the identity you are using in the application pool is getting denied access.

- Download Process Monitor and follow the instructions on this post:
       http://www.iislogs.com/articles/processmonitorw3wp/ (This tutorial shows how to do it on IIS, with WAMP you will need to find the .exe process that runs on memory)
- Find the registry key where the process `w3wp.exe` is being denied access. That in the case of IIS, not sure what's the name of the process in WAMP but the procedure is the same. 
  In my case:

  ```
  HKLM\Software\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\SQL Native Client 10.0
  ```
- Run regedit and find the key
- Right click and go to Permissions
- Add Network Service to the list and give it Read permissions.
- Recycle the app pool and it should work

Comment: Yes...you're right. That also worked for me. I stumbled upon it a while ago and I totally forgot I even had the question here. Thanks for taking the time to confirm that:D

Comment: But what if I do not get "w3wp.exe" in Task Manager..??

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid w3wp.exe is an IIS process. If you don't have that running that means your IIS is not running.

Comment: @FedericoGiust-So does that mean I cannot connect to my sql server 2008..? Sorry for dumb question as I am new to sql connection.

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid Are you trying to connect to mysql or ms sql? Which server are you running? IIS, Apache (WAMP,XAMPP)?

Comment: @FedericoGiust-Sorry that was my typing mistake..I want to connect to mssql and I am using WampServer with Apache 2.2.22 and php 5.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

[sqlsrv_connect PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)

Try this approach to see what the error actually is:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
} else {
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: I've edited my post with the error I'm now getting. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: From your error, it looks like you do not have the Microsoft SQL Server 2011 Native Client. It provided a link to download it. See the third post here: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,53541,printview,page=1

Answer (score 2):

Based on your setup, you may need to revert to the `mssql_connect` and corresponding functions. This works fine with mssql 2008 and you don't usually lose meaningful functionality.

Here's an example of setting up a connection to the database. Depending on your configuration you may have to add port information, etc.

```
$hostname = "server.domain.com";
$database = "DatabaseName";
$username = "LocalSQLUserName";
$password = "P@ssw0rd";
$Connection = mssql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
```

If you are running on a XAMP environment, then it would stand to reason that you are running everything locally.  If that's the case, your server would be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` and you can define your own accounts in SQL. As I said, I don't use Windows accounts myself, but you can add an NT account to your "server" and then in SQL Server Management tool set that user to have access to the DB you are using. Then you have set the account and password and know what they are.  If you have trouble with the user account, you can try `computerName\userName`.

If you are not the admin, you'll need to get the relevant information from them.

Comment: I don't need a lot of functionality, just some basic queries into JSON format. One more thing...what are the parameters "server-name", "user" and "password" if I'm using the simplest, default Windows Authentication...?

Comment: I'll be in the office soon and fill out my answer then

Comment: @Eugen, I've edited my answer to show an example of my connection.  As for Windows Auth, I personally avoid it for security reasons.  I always create an account local to the specific database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. I'm just trying to set a basic webservice up to test and showcase something for my employer

Comment: Been there.  Ping me back if you're still having issues.

Comment: Hmm...now I'm getting "call to undefined function mssql_connect", even though I have sqlsrv drivers installed and they show up in phpinfo();

Comment: Here are some links that might help.  They are a bit dated, but should still be valid: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=197064.msg888989#msg888989  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674320/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect-in-php

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me! I finally got mssql_connect working by using XAMPP 1.7.3, but now I need to figure out what the serverName, userName and password are for Windows Authentication