# sqlsvr_connect() not connecting!? Trying to connect with php

Tags: php, database, sql-server-2008

Im trying to connect to a ms sql database, but I'm running into a timeout error...

I already installed the microsoft driver by adding and enabling,

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
```

in my php.ini file, and added the dll into my php extenstions, which is in my "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext"... and also, my extension_dir in my php.ini is also "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext"

I am using this code to connect...

```
phpinfo();

$serverName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/sqlexpress";

$connectionInfo = array(
     "Database"=>"dbname", 
     "UID"=>"username", 
     "PWD"=>"password");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if($conn){
     echo "Connection established.\n";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

The phpinfo() is showing that sqlsrv is indeed in Registered PHP Streams.  The problem is not an undefined function, but it just keeps loading... it doesn't timeout, it doesn't give me an error, it just keeps thinking...  Am I missing something? please help!

Comment: I have the same extension loaded. I can't get my app to recognize either sqlsrv_connect or mssql_connect. Both fail as undefined functions.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: If so, please accept a relevant answer. If not, use `if($conn === false){` and `die("Connection established.\n");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$serverName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/sqlexpress";
```

should be:

```
$serverName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\sqlexpress";
```

Also, see the answer to this question: [Connecting to SQL Server 2008 through PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254329/connecting-to-sql-server-2008-through-php)