# sqlsrv_connect: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, wamp

I am facing difficulties in connecting PHP with SQL SERVER 2008 running on a remote computer. I have php version 5.4.3 and apache 2.2.22. I already have SQL SERVER 2008 running on my computer. I have following files included in my wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext folder:

- php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

On running simple code like

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn )
{
 echo "Connection established.\n";
}
else
{
 echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
Connection could not be established. Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
        [1] => -49 [code] => -49
        [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 
        [1] => 0 [code] => 0
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    )
)
```

But I dont know why I am being asked for **Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client** installation.

phpI have tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9921725/1465910) but with no success.

Thanks in Advance.

***UPDATE 1:***

I downloaded php 5.3.1 and followed [this tutorial](http://forum.ragezone.com/f723/setup-wampserver-mssql-841598/) and scripts works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php): The SQLSRV extension requires that the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client be Installed on the same Computer that is running PHP.

Comment: @Ene-Thanks for quick reply...but should it do if I downgrade my php version to 5.3..?? According to you which one is a better solution...?

Comment: @Ene- Also a doubt that will Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client run in Microsoft xp..??

Comment: afaik the current driver version (3) only supports the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client, and driver version 3 is not supported on XP. The version 2.0 driver works with PHP 5.2.4 or later, but not with PHP 5.4. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx

Comment: @Ene-So is it ok if i downgrade to 5.3.313..?? And then what..wont i be needing sqlsrv for that..??

Comment: I can't try it myself, but maybe worth a try. Please post your results.

Answer (score 1):

Install ODBC Driver(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434).
Now I can  **Access the remote MSSQL Server without installing the MSSQL Server** in my computer