# Can anyone decipher an error message I get when trying to store form data on MS SQL using php?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I attempted to connect to an `Microsoft SQL` database and store html form data in it using `php` but was unable to.

At first I attempted using the `mssql` syntax but realized that it was abandoned past `5.2` (I'm running `5.3`). Then I attempted to connect using the `sqlsrv` syntax but that required a driver and editing the php.ini file -- which I did only to receive this error message pertaining to the MS SQL Native Client:

```
> Connection COULD NOT be establishedArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )
```

A `phpinfo` file shows that `sqlsrv` is installed and I've deleted and reinstalled the drivers and native client twice already to no avail..........

Here is the stack:

- Windows 2003 server
- IIS 6 web host
- local install of MS SQL 2008 (previously was attempting to connect to a remote MS SQL 2014 database
- PHP version 3.1.3

Comment: You have noticed it's after SQL Server 2012 Native Client in the error right, and not 2008?

Comment: Doesn't it just request the latest version?

Comment: What determines the error message? I mean what application is printing it?

Comment: This message seems to be printed by php sql server extension.

This link talk about similar issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254329/connecting-to-sql-server-2008-through-php?rq=1