# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_query()

Tags: php, sql-server

So I keep getting this error when I want to query something to the ms sql server..

The connection is made with the database but the queries seem to fail.

The error log contains this:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mssql_query()
```

The code on the php:

```
session_start();
include_once("connect.php");
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";
$res = mssql_query ($sql) or die(mssql_error());

if (mssql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
    $row = mssql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['Username'];
    $_SESSION['afdeling'] = $row['Afdeling'];
    $_SESSION['mail'] = $row['Mail'];
              header("Location: test.php");
    exit();
} else {
    echo "Invalid login information. Please return to the previous page.";
    exit(); }  }  ?>
```

Does anybody knows what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

connect.php code:

```
<?php
$serverName = "MTN-TEST"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"PROCES_TEST", "UID"=>"blaaa", "PWD"=>"blooo");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "<span style='color:green;'>Connection established.</span><br />";
}else{
     echo "<span style='color:red;'>Connection could not be established.</span><br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php

Comment: @Innominatum : You have tagged this both mysql and sql-server. Which DB are you actually using ?

Comment: Are you sure connection to MS-SQL server is made correctly ? can you share code of connect.php ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have the MS SQL Drivers installed.
You can check this with `phpinfo();`

On ***Linux*** you need mssql.so or sybase.so
With debian its `apt-get install php5-sybase`

For ***windows*** take a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc793139%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Drivers need to be configured for PHP to find the function mssql_...

You could also look at PDO DB classes as they can connect to any DBS, you need the drivers installed tho.

Comment: Took a look into it, the mssql library is missing in PHPinfo();
Any idea where I can get it for windows? :)

Comment: That windows link to msdn did hit the spot. it works now 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If your connect.php code returns "Connection established.", it's mean you installed MS SQL Drivers correctly.
You have to use `sqlsrv_query`function instead of `mssql_query`.
The correct form of this command is:

```
     <?php
                $serverName = "serverName"; 
                $options = array(  "UID" => "sa",  "PWD" => "Password",  "Database" => "DBname");
                $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $options);

                if( $conn ) {
                     echo "Connection established.<br />";

                     $query='select * from test';
                     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

                }else{
                     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
                     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                }

            ?>
```

you can learn more here:

["PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_select_db() in c:\...appscript.php on line 16"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474996/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-select-db-in-c-appscrip)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [mssql_get_last_message()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php) for mssql errors