# Running SQL Query in PHP File

Tags: php, sql-server

I have established a connection with my SQL Database through Windows Authentication in my php file.  However I'm not sure how the syntax will look if I wanted to display a simple SQL query such as (Select * from Media) on the php page that shows an entire table.  I tried a few methods but it displayed a fatal error.

Here is my code for the php:

```
     <?php

     $serverName = "172.20.90.170,5050"; //serverName\instanceName

     // Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
     // The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
     $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"TestDB");
     $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

     if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
     }else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
     }
     $version = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM MEDIA');
     $row = mssql_fetch_array($version);
     echo $row[0];

     ?>
```

Fatal Error:

```
  Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_query()
```

This establishes a succesful connection but what would I need to change in my code for this query to run error free and display the required output?

Comment: ...keep using `sqlsrv_` functions?

Comment: You're using `sqlsrv_connect`, why then do you try to use `mssql_query`?  Don't you want to use `sqlsrv_query`?

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103751/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-query
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402713/how-to-get-mssql-work-with-php-5-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you're new to the PHP world, BUT, I advise you to use the PDO class. You will have more facility to do what you want.

Here's a sample using your data.
If you study, you can understand.

```
try
{
    $connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=172.20.90.170;Database=TestDB", "YOUR_USERNAME", "YOUR_PASSWORD");
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM);
}catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die('Connection could not be established.<br />');
}

try
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM MEDIA';
    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}catch (Exception $e)
{
    die('Cant fetch rows.');
}

foreach ($result as $r)
{
    print_r($r); // do what you want here
}
```

Comment: but doesnt this use the sql server authentication method since it's asking for the username and password?

Comment: okay so this is displaying the data but not in a table format its just line after line, do you know how I could display it as a table like in SQL?

Comment: is it possible for you to edit your code to display it in a table format? I just want to test it.

Comment: Sure. In the foreach loop, you can do this.

echo '<table>';
foreach ($result as $r)
{
 echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $r['column_name1'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $r['column_name2'] . '</td>';
 echo '<tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

Comment: it's still showing them as rows of lines after lines but just a large space between each row now.  Still not in a table format.

Comment: I was trying to organize the code here in comments, but I dont know how to do. But the code is there.

Comment: Is there a way to show a table thats like SQL? Or if not atleast similar to SQL?

Comment: You take the data from the database and handles them.
What I have shown to you is a way to show like the database shows to you, in a HTML table.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are mixing two different API's (`sqlsrv_` and `mssql_`).

If you're using `sqlsrv_`, then a simple statement could look like:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database" => "database", "UID" => "username", "PWD" => "password" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( "Server", $connectionInfo );

$stmt = "SELECT [column] FROM [table] WHERE [id] = ?";
$params = array( $id );

$query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $stmt, $params );
if( $query === false ) {
    print( print_r( sqlsrv_errors() ) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
    echo $row['column'];
}

sqlsrv_close( $conn );
```

**Resources**

- [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296161%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) (contains both Windows & SQL Server authentication examples)

Comment: this is for the SQL Server Authentication.  How would you place the select statement in my question with the Windows Authentication method?

Comment: @omarK The PHP docs show how you would connect using Windows Auth.

Comment: I'm not sure but now it's just displaying an empty white page when I tried to run it with your code.

Comment: @omarK Do you have `error_reporting` enables and `display_errors` on?

Answer (score 0):

As others says in the comments, you have two options:

```
1. Use sqlsrv_query
2. Install MSSQL support to PHP.
```

Sincerely, I prefer use mssql_* stack of functions. If you use ubuntu, you can install MSSQL support simply:

```
aptitude install php5-sybase
```