# "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_select_db() in c:\...appscript.php on line 16"

Tags: php, sql-server, iis-7.5, php-5.3

Folks, Im trying to run a basic php script in cmd prompt which connects to sql server 2012 on my local machine, its gives me the following error..."PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_select_db() in c:...appscript.php on line 16"

Here is my script, im not very familiar with php but have been playing around with it and im unsure if my script is correct..

```
  <?php
    $Server = "";
    $User = "";
    $Pass = "";
    $DB = "";

    //$SQLKEY = "";

    //connection to the database
    //$dbconn = sqlsrv_connect($Server, $User, $Pass)
    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $User, "PWD" => $Pass, "Database" => $DB);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $Server, $connectionInfo);
    //or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $Server");

   //select a database to work with
    $selected = mssql_select_db($DB, $connectionInfo)
   or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

   //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
   $query = "SELECT name from test ";

   //execute the SQL query and return records
  $result = mssql_query($query);

  $numRows = mssql_num_rows($result);
   echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>";

  //display the results
  while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<br>" . $row["name"];
  }
  //close the connection
  mssql_close($dbconn);
  ?>
```

Be great if someone could help or least give me a few pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using wrong functions. You should use only functions from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-begin-transaction.php

It seems there is no need to select db (there is no sqlserv_select_db function).

You should change your mssql_query to sqlsrv_query and the same for other functions and you should look at PHP manual because some functions may missing.

Comment: is there any way i can print a query or something from the database so that i confirm that the script is working, it says connection established but just to verify access aswell? cheers

Comment: Of course you have query method so you can get something from database table. Just look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php for example

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the MSSQL extension.

<strike>http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php</strike> (dead link)
Last working version captured by archive.org:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200920214312/http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php

Comment: Im using the extension php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll because the php version im using doesnt support mssql extension....

Comment: What version are you using? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986804/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mssql-connect might help as well